# как настроить автоконфигурацию oauth2 webClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, webclient

Есть приложение, с oauth2
где параметры WebClient указываются через been

```
@Bean
    public WebClient getWebClient() {
        ClientRegistration.Builder clientRegestrationBuilder = ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("authProvider");
        clientRegestrationBuilder.clientId("superad");
        clientRegestrationBuilder.clientSecret("d000f0f8-9f0d-451c-9257-0720be5839e7");
        clientRegestrationBuilder.tokenUri("https://leantegra.leantegra.com/api/public/token/");
        clientRegestrationBuilder.authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS);
        clientRegestrationBuilder.clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC);
        ClientRegistration clientRegistration = clientRegestrationBuilder.build();



        ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository repo = new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);

        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(repo,
                new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
        return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build();
    }
```

Но на сколько я понимаю, spring boot может избавить от такой конфигурации, используя application.properties файл, например:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.authProvider.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.authProvider.client-id=superad
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.authProvider.client-secret=d000а0а8-9f0d-451c-9257-0720be5839e7
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.authProvider.token-uri=https://leantegra.leantegra.com/api/public/token/
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.authentication.user-info-authentication-method=BASIC
```

без определения бина. Как это сделать?